# Off-the-shelf micro fluid dispenser

Tags: electronics

Need a way to dispense micro liter amounts of water (lets say 1-10ul). Only thing I've found is piezoelectric dispensers and they are >$100. Any suggestions?

I can build, but preferably would be an off-the-shelf component.

Comment: Piezoelectric dispensers may be expensive, but they certainly count as "off-the-shelf".  Are you asking how to build one for less than $100?  Otherwise, this is a bit offtopic as a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: I think he's looking for an alternative technology.

Comment: Right, was asking for alternatives, like I know you could use a solenoid and a pump, but I don't know if it's feasible at that resolution. Was hoping someone with more experience could give me a hint at alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

It may be practical to adapt some ink-jet printer heads to dispense water.

An ink-jet printer head projects a stream of droplets.  Droplet volume varies widely among printers; typically, it's smaller in newer printers.  Eg, a fairly-comprehensive 1998 [inkjet tutorial](http://www.imaging.org/ist/resources/tutorials/inkjet.cfm) at imaging.org says early HP 800-series ink-jets produced 6000 drops per second with 32 pL per drop, which works out to about 5.2 seconds to deliver 1 µL of ink.  (I don't know if the DPS is per nozzle or per head.) The later 890C with a 192-nozzle head produced 12000 drops per second with 10 pL per drop, or about 8.3 s to deliver 1 µL of ink.  As noted in a 2010 [computerworld.com blog](http://blogs.computerworld.com/16162/hp_explains_why_printer_ink_is_so_expensive), the “Photosmart 8250 uses 3,900 nozzles to deliver 122 million drops per second onto the paper.”

(Note, with a [drop-on-demand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkjet_printing#Drop-on-demand) printhead, you could count drops – that is, control the number of pulses –  vs turning the head on for a timed interval.)

<strike>An article called [Non-Contact Liquid Handling: Basics and Technologies](http://www.labautopedia.org/mw/index.php/Non-Contact_Liquid_Handling:_Basics_and_Technologies) at labautopedia.org gives a good introduction to several techniques now in use for delivering small amounts of liquid.</strike> *[Edit, May 2015: Article is gone; instead see [Small Volume Pipetting](http://www.labautopedia.org/mw/index.php?title=Small_volume_pipetting) and perhaps [Microfluidic Sample Transport](http://www.labautopedia.org/mw/index.php?title=Microfluidic_sample_transport).]*   Among other topics it covers physics of 
droplet formation and illustrates several valving techniques.

<strike>Another useful survey, “Dispensing systems for miniaturized diagnostics”, is at [ivdtechnology.com](http://www.ivdtechnology.com/article/dispensing-systems-miniaturized-diagnostics).</strike> *[Edit, May 2015: Website is gone; perhaps see [a search for related articles at mddionline.com](http://www.mddionline.com/search/apachesolr_search/Dispensing%20systems%20for%20miniaturized%20diagnostics)]*

The [wikipedia inkjet article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkjet_printing) referenced earlier and a [wikipedia microdispensing article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdispensing) are helpful but seem superficial compared to the imaging.org and labautopedia.org articles.  Also see an [nlm.nih.gov article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17588671) about dispensing an enzyme-conjugated solution into an ELISA plate by adapting ink-jet printers, by Lonini et al.

Answer (score 3):

I have used small solenoid valves with a fixed displacement to dispense small droplets. For example, the valve I used consistently pumped 0.5 uL from one orifice to the other every time it was switched. That particular valve was not intended to be used as a pump, but there was no reason it couldn't be. There are other solenoids which are intended to be used that way.

The valve I used costs less than $100. Unfortunately I can't share the specific part number, but you should be able to find some help from [The Lee Company](http://www.theleeco.com/products.cfm), or [SMC](http://www.smcusa.com/smc.aspx), who sell these types of valves. Lee will definitely sell small quantities. I don't know about SMC. Either one should be able to provide you with samples.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to dispense a single reagent (water), then you are best off using a microdispensing valve based solution. I do not know that you will find something for less than $100, but if you went that route, you would be looking for parts like [this](http://www.theleecoefs.com/EFSWEB2.NSF/MDG!OpenView).

There are other technologies out there (syringe based, capillary action based, pipette based), but none are suited as well as a microdispensing valve for bulk reagent dispensing in the 1-10uL volume range. You can find more technical information about microdispensing [here](http://www.theleecoefs.com/PDF.nsf/bdb21d9b7952d46a85256a400071dc4c/e9c48210dfa8354f85256cc4004de470/%24FILE/VHS-STARTER%20KIT%20MANUAL-B2.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Just how precise do you need to be? We build medical instruments and a $100 pump would be considered pretty damn cheap around here. The most common technology is a syringe pump controlled by a stepper motor, but for precise, very repeatable dispense, fluid dynamic effects have to be considered. e.g., wicking off the droplet at the probe tip can have a dramatic impact on accuracy.